# VBA, how to obtain last column as range in a given range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple question, which unfortunately I can not resolve. Thus would appreciate your help. Here is the thing:
I should obtain last column from the range as a range. For example, if I have A26:D32, I should get D26:D32 as a result and input into the loop.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Function getSmth(CustomCol As Range)
    Dim i As Double
        For Each cell In CustomCol  'start of the loop. CustomCol here should return D26:D32 already
            If cell.Value > i Then
                i = cell.Value
            End If
        Next
....

End Function
```

What I have tried to do was writing CustomCol.Columns(6), as I know the last column, but it did not work out.

Would really be glad for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Function GetLasRangeCol(rng As Range) As Range
    Set GetLasRangeCol = rng.Columns(rng.Columns.Count).Cells
End Function
```

That you may use in your calling code as:

```
For Each cell In GetLasRangeCol(myRange)
```

Where ‘myRange’ is a valid range reference, i.e: either a variable of Range type or some Range object (like ‘Range(“A5:B21”)’) to get last column out of

Comment: Thank you for your response! I used your solution because it is a bit shorter :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a shorter way to it, but this does the trick:

```
Function lastColumn(rg As Range) As Range
    Set lastColumn = Range(Cells(Range(Split(rg.Address(0, 0), ":")(0)).Row, _
        Range(Split(rg.Address(0, 0), ":")(1)).Column).Address(0, 0) _
        & ":" & Split(rg.Address(0, 0), ":")(1))
End Function
```

It take a `Range` object as a parameter and returns a `Range` object.

**Example Usage:**

```
Sub demo()
    Dim rg As Range, rg2 As Range
    Set rg = Range("A26:D32")
    Set rg2 = lastColumn(rg)
    Debug.Print "The last column is: " & rg2.Address
End Sub
```

...returns: `The last column is: $D$26:$D$32`

There's probably a "tidier" method (perhaps using [`INTERSECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Intersect)) but this will work fine.

---

**Explanation:**

This is the same function as above, but broken down so it's easier to understand:

```
Function lastColumn(rg As Range) As Range

    Dim firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol, leftPart, rightPart

    leftPart = Split(rg.Address(0, 0), ":")(0)
    rightPart = Split(rg.Address(0, 0), ":")(1)
    firstRow = Range(leftPart).Row
    firstCol = Range(leftPart).Column
    lastCol = Range(rightPart).Column

    Set lastColumn = Range(Cells(firstRow, lastCol), Range(rightPart))

End Function
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Application.`Range` Property** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.range)
- MSDN : [**Range.`Cells` Property** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells)
- Office Support : [**`Split` Function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Your solution works! Though, if you do not mind I've taken DisplayName's solution as it is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last column as a range, then
    myRange.Columns(myRange.Columns.Count)

If you want the number of the last column then
    myRange.Columns(myRange.Columns.Count).Column

Answer (score -1):

To find last column in row 1:

```
Dim LastCol As Long

LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for the last column in a row. They said the last column in a *given range*.  See the example given in the question. (Also take a look at tips in [answer].)